# Induction proof with big O

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I'm trying to prove using the induction method, however I'm not able to go forward

Question:

$x_{n+1}
\le  2x_n + 3x_{n−1} + n^2
$ , where 
$x_0 = 1, x_1 = 1$.

Prove that $x_n = O(3.1^n)$.

Appreciate any help,

Comment: I edited your question. Is the result what you meant? Please learn MathJax.

Comment: Appreciate it. First post here. Thanks for inform me about MathJax

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Suppose
$x_k \le ab^k$
for $k = n, n-1$.

Then
$x_{n+1}
\le  2x_n + 3x_{n−1} + n^2
\le  2ab^n + 3ab^{n-1} + n^2
$.

If we can show that
$2ab^n + 3ab^{n-1} + n^2
\le ab^{n+1}$,
we are done.

This is
$ n^2
\le ab^{n+1}-2ab^n - 3ab^{n-1} 
= ab^{n-1}(b^2-2b - 3)
$.

Now use
$b^2-2b - 3
=(b-3)(b+1)
$
for
$b=3.1$
to find an $a$
for which this is true
for all $n$.

You can actually do this
for any $b > 3$.
Do you why this fails
for $0 \le b \le 3$?

Note:
$b^2-2b-3$
is called the
characteristic polynomial
of the recurrence.
Its roots
give important information
about the growth
of solutions
to the recurrence.